# Making some cloth stitches stronger than the others

Tags: cloth-simulation

My animation goes as follows: For the first few frames, the cloth stitching does its thing. It's a basic raincoat with a hood, and the only thing holding it together is a single edge that completes a circle around the character's neck.

[image: like so]

There's also a wind in the background. And after a few frames, the character starts to run.

Problem is, when the character is running, the raincoat gets torn off the shoulders (see animation). I can make the sewing force stronger, but it ruins the stitches that are holding the hood together.

(I also tried weight painting those vertices, but I'm not exactly sure what it did)

Is there a setting I can use to make that particular edge to have a stronger sewing force than the others?

Blend file: https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZAYtHXZ1LeH1wqXMj72wlbklg4dSkIe4RUk (physics are baked)

Rendered and animated: https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZ3YtHXZjhwUwcS4bL57LC4d5lHPipxOTEz7

Answer (score 1):

In the real world, you would not close the raincoat with a single thread at the front of the neck. The edge/seam pulls the fabric together in the clothing simulation, but the single edge doesn't work well for collision detection.

The solution is to turn the edge into a face, so that real geometry exists. This face is treated as a small piece of cloth and also has the usual cloth properties like tension strength, stiffness, bending, etc. and can resist inertia better than an edge. You can adjust these settings if needed.

I tried that and it works. The next problem, however, is that when the character is in a full run, the hands, knees & feet will beat the fabric in an unnatural way and it comes to glitches. It might be better to move the cape back a bit so that nothing is in the way at the front when he runs. (That is, deform the circle into a semicircle before the simulation.)